# Alamofire POST route returning data

Tags: ios, swift, api, post, alamofire

So I am trying to POST to my API on my iPhone app. When I POST I want to be able to return a struct that has data. How would I do that? So far I have

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "API_URL", parameters)
```

Is there some way to store what the API gives back?

Comment: You should really read the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). All your questions have detailed code samples and explanations. Just make sure you are looking at the version of the README that matches the version of Alamofire you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "API_URL, parameters).responseJSON{ request, response, result in

print(result.value)
}
```

If you want to use the resulting JSON in an easy manner - I would suggest using [SWIFTY JSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Thanks! How would I extract the data from result? for example if I had the API return two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.If you are using the latest version of Alamofire.

Simply try this(If the returning data is in JSON)

```
let url1 = "http://yoururl.com"
let head = [ "Accept": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"] // Adding headers
let p = ["Email":"anything","Password": "123"] // Adding parameters if any

Alamofire.request(.POST,url1, parameters: p, encoding : .JSON, headers : head)
.responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

}
```

Comment: Thank you! 

How would I then get the data from response.data? 

For example if the JSON object had 2 strings that I would like to print out.

Also what is the difference between response.request/response/data/result, and ones without response

Comment: post the json response you are getting

Comment: My json response is

"success" : true

"message" : some string

"token" : a long string.  ~~~~~ I am trying to not use SWIFTY, because my JSON data is simple.

Comment: post complete json response

Comment: you can see the difference just pasting the above code.